# Aggregate/Sum data set by week and by product in R

Tags: r, date, sum, aggregate, cbind

I have a very large data set that I would like to aggregate both by week/month and by product(a few thousand). Is there a way to do so with a data set in the following format?

```
Date           product product2 product3
03/03/2011       1        0        7
04/08/2011       3        8        2
03/05/2015       6        3       89
03/01/2017       1        0        2
03/03/2017       6        1        6
```

which would yield the following:

```
Date           product product2 product3
wk1-032011       1        0        7
wk2-042011       3        8        2
wk1-032015       6        3       89
wk1-032017       7        1        8


df <- structure(list(Date = c("03/03/2011", "04/04/2011", "03/05/2015", "03/01/2017", "03/03/2017"),
             product= c(1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 6L),
             product2= c(0L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 1L), 
             product3= c(7L, 2L, 89L, 2L, 6L)), 
             .Names= c("Date", "product", "product2", "product3"), 
             class= "data.frame", row.names=c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can use `as.Date` to convert your character df$Date into a Date variable and then use `format` to with the proper formatting to convert the date into a character variable indicating weekly dates. `aggregate` is then used to perform the aggregation by the new variable.

```
aggregate(df[2:4], list("weeks"=format(as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%W")), FUN=sum)
    weeks product product2 product3
1 2011-09       1        0        7
2 2011-14       3        8        2
3 2015-09       6        3       89
4 2017-09       7        1        8
```

See `?strptime` for other date conversions.

---

As @akrun mentions in the comments, the `data.table` analog to the above base R code is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum),
          by=.(weeks = format(as.IDate(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%W"))]
```

Here, `setDT` converts the data.frame into a data.table, `lapply...` calculates the sum where `.SD` stands for the data.table. This sum is calculated by each unique element that is produced from `format(as.IDate(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%W")` where the conversion uses data.table's `as.IDate` in place of the base R `as.Date`.

Comment: Or using `data.table` `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), .(weeks = format(as.IDate(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%W"))]`